# rails - after_update occurring on .save for new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, callback, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have two models: UserNotification and Schedule.  When a schedule is created, one type of user notification is created (the first line of code).  When a schedule is updated, another type of user notification is created (the second line of code).  For some reason, after_update is occurring after a save (i only want it to happen after an update).  Here is code in code:

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
   after_save 'UserNotification.schedule_created(@user)'
   after_update 'UserNotification.schedule_updated(@user)'
end
```

Am I missing something.  How do I get after_save to only happen after I say @schedule.save and after_update to only occur after I do @schedule.update_attributes(...) ?  Here is the controller code if it helps:

```
if @schedule.save   
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created schedule."
    redirect_to profile_path(current_user.profile_name)  #change to project path later
end
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Under the hood, `save` calls `create` on a new record, and `update` on a persisted record.

The `after_save` callback is called both when a record has been created and updated.

The `after_create` and `after_update` callbacks are called on new and persisted record respectively.

You'd need to change your `after_save` callback to `after_create` if you only want it to run after creating an object.

More on ActiveRecord callbacks can be found in [the Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html).

Comment: Great, thanks,.thats correct.  Unfortunately, I asked the wrong question.  Would you mind also taking a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20568413/rails-how-do-i-change-new-save-to-create