# Rails - how do I change .new/.save to .create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, callback, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models: Schedule and Project.  Project has_one Schedule and Schedule belongs_to Project.  When I create a schedule, I do:

```
def create
  @schedule = Schedule.new(schedule_params)
  @schedule.project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  if @schedule.save
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully created schedule."
    redirect_to profile_path(current_user)
  end
end
```

This works.  However, I added an after_create callback and an after_update callback to make notifications.  A 'new schedule created' notification when the schedule is created, and a 'your schedule has been updated' notification when it is updated.  The problem is that in the controller I use @schedule.new and @schedule.save, not @schedule.create.  I need to change my controller code to use .create so the after_create callback will work.  I have already tried using the after_save callback, but that gets called whenever the schedule is updated as well so that won't work.

Because of the way I define @schedule and @schedule,project, I cannot figure out how to change the code I have above to use @schedule.create.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Everyone did a good job on answering this question, but the answers essentially led to another very similar problem that i have posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20569839/after-update-is-being-called-when-object-is-created-should-only-be-called-on-u .  I'm still reading through the answers and I'll select a winner for this question shortly.

Answer (score 1):

`after_create` will be fired when after the record is saved for the first time, ie. if `@schedule.save` succeeds. There is no need to specifically change it to be `create` instead of `new`.

Answer (score 0):

The method `.create` is either on the class:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/create/class

For example, `User.create`, not `@user.create`.

**OR** it is on an association:

`@user.projects.create(params[:project])`

If you want to trigger an `after_create` callback here, it needs to be defined on `Project` not on `User`.

Comment: I have already invoked them from my model.  I am asking how do I change what I have in my controller from a .new/.save to .create?

Comment: .create is a class method, not an instance method. Updated my answer.

Comment: I am defining after_create on Schedule.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    if @project.schedule.create(schedule_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully created schedule."
        redirect_to profile_path(current_user)
    end
end
```